# Form not submitting hidden input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is hidden input in code which must be TRY by default and be changeable using dropdown box.
Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fiyat</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fiyat" class="form-control js-listing-price js-numeric" name="price.amount" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn btn-default">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="js-currency-preview">TL</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                            <li><a data-value="TRY">TL</a></li>
                            <li><a data-value="USD">$</a></li>
                            <li><a data-value="EUR">€</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="hidden" value="TRY" class="js-listing-price-currency js-currency" name="price.currency">
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.js-currency-preview').text($(this).text());
    $('.js-listing-price-currency').val($(this).data('value'));
  });
};
```

All other fields are working except this js-currency field.

Comment: after selecting any of this dropdown options $('.js-listing-price-currency').val() changes, but when pressed to submit button its not submitting this value.

Comment: Just wondering, do you have a `<form>` tag around all of that? It doesn't show here and it is probably important.

Comment: `$('.js-listing-price-currency').val($(this).attr('data-value'));`

Comment: @Rafee $('.js-listing-price-currency').val($(this).data('value')); also works, I'm checking it using $('.js-listing-price-currency').val() in the console. And yes, tested using this, and same result.

Comment: @AlexisWilke ofcourse i have <form> tag at the top of html page. This is the only variable that gives error.

Comment: @EminMastizada Check my code again, its working with element attributes FYI

Comment: price.amount is submitting btw.

Comment: @Rafee I already tested, and I think $(this).data('value') and $(this).attr('data-value') are the same things.

Comment: How does the submit happen? Are you using jQuery or is the normal submit from the browser used? It shouldn't make a difference, but this is strange...

Comment: @AlexisWilke already solved. Problem was hidden input in Backbone Binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Backbone Binder can't see hidden changes in hidden inputs they mustn't change in page.
It can be solved by adding `trigger('change');` to the code:

```
$('.js-listing-price-currency').val($(this).data('value')).trigger('change');
```