# can not submit input hidden when change value for it

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i have same problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53702996/10319107)

But I can not find the answer for that!

I was review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22354214/10319107), but it is not working for me!

Please help
my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#create_lop_monhoc_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var tenmh = button.data('tenmh')
    var mamh = button.data('mamh')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('#input_tenmh').val(tenmh).trigger("change")
    modal.find('#tenmh').text(tenmh).trigger("change")
    modal.find('#input_mamh').val(mamh).trigger("change")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade " id="create_lop_monhoc_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="/monhoc" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="input_mamh" name="mamh" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="input_tenmh" name="tenmh" />
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4 id="mamh"></h4>
          <div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Crate</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_lop_monhoc_modal" data-tenmh="tenmh" data-mamh="mamh">                   
  Open Modal
</button>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You should post your code in here

Comment: becouse i am creating same code with that post, i was post it!

Comment: Can you try to show hidden value after changing?

Comment: i want submit value of it after changing @Tomato32

Comment: @nguyễnmạnh: Yeah, I know. I mean that you can use console.log or debugger to check the hidden value before submit :))

Answer (score -1):

You need learn javascript for put value or get data attribute. Try these

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#create_lop_monhoc_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var tenmh = button.attr('data-tenmh');
    var mamh = button.attr('data-mamh');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('#input_tenmh').val('tenmh').trigger("change")
    modal.find('#tenmh').text('tenmh').trigger("change")
    modal.find('#input_mamh').val('mamh').trigger("change")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade " id="create_lop_monhoc_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="/monhoc" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="input_mamh" name="mamh" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="input_tenmh" name="tenmh" />
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4 id="mamh"></h4>
          <div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Crate</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_lop_monhoc_modal" data-tenmh="tenmh" data-mamh="mamh">                   
  Open Modal
</button>
```

Comment: There is no difference between button.attr('data-tenmh') and button.data('tenmh'), and i was tried 'modal.find('#input_tenmh').val('tenmh').trigger("change")', but it is not working

Comment: i was tried this: https://jsbin.com/tideceb/edit?html,js,console,output , it was changed value but it is not submit to serve

Comment: @nguyễnmạnh : There's different, and thats not how u did on javascript. If u try inspect your browser  button.data('tenmh') will show data not defined.